# Compile for 10.5/10.6 & PPC

Tags: xcode, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion, powerpc, vmware-fusion

I'm needing to compile a C++/C/Objective-C project for 10.5 (ppc, intel)+ however Xcode 4+ (using 4.6) drops support for 10.6 and i believe Xcode 4 completely dropped support for 10.4/ppc. I have read existing StackOverflow and other posts about installing Xcode 3.2.6 on Mountain Lion but i don't want to do this if it's unconfirmed/will break my system..

I've tried virtualising Snow Leopard in a VMware Fusion 5 Pro VM but it doesn't allow me to as it is not a server version.

Besides buying a Snow Leopard Server DVD, how else can i compile my project for 10.4+ (ppc,intel)? I am currently running OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.3. Setting the deployment target does not work in my Xcode version, doesn't compile. I've also considered virtualising Lion, however i do not have a backup copy of (my purchased via app store) install dmg/app and i can't seem to find the download in the App Store.

Can anyone suggest what i should do or am i basically left with one option.. Dual boot Snow Leopard?.

Thanks!

Comment: There should be a compatible version of XCode on the Leopard/Snow-leopard install DVDs.  Even the non-server versions should have it.  As for virtualization, Apple has relaxed the restrictions on running client versions of OSX in VMs, though I'm not sure if it applies retroactively to older versions.  Other VMs may not have the lockout, like VirtualBox or Parallels

Comment: @GordonM VMware Fusion 5 (pro) doesn't let me install SL client... ?

Comment: Never used it, but googling says that VMWare fusion 4.1 will let you install client versions.

Comment: @GordonM where do i download that? can't find on google

Comment: Gordon is correct that Apple has finally allowed OS X to be virtualized (although only on Apple hardware).  Apple has not back-ported this new EULA to their old OSes.  Fusion has always included a check to ensure EULA compliance.  It's correct that 4.1 accidentally bypassed this check, but we updated to 4.1.1 posthaste to correct this error.
As a software engineer, I can't in good consciousness recommend a method that breaks EULAs, so you're right: buy Server, or dual-boot. Note that later hardware doesn't support earlier OSes, so you'll have to check. Ex: I can't install SL on my rMBP.